# 2nd ProxyPass not working on Bitnami MEAN Apache 2.4 box

Tags: apache, virtualhost, bitnami, proxypass

I am running a Bitnami MEAN Lightsail box with a react app running on port 3000 and an express app on port 9000 on Apache 2.4 which is running TLS on port 443.

Apache is able to proxy to the React app and display it.   The React app makes calls to the web service, which should be accessible at localhost:9000 - but instead getting denied with a [authz_core:error] AH01630 Error when I check logs.

Doing a netstat, I do see that my localhost:3000 proxy is an IPv4 address - 0.0.0.0:3000   BUT,my express app is shown running IPv6 so it's address is ::1:9000.

Does anyone think this might be the reason, and if so what is the best approach for solve.

I have my ProxyPass statements in the correct order in the VirtualHost entry, editing the bitnami-ssl.conf file and  going from specific to most general path as mentioned in some other posts as a pitfall with multiple ProxyPass entries.

```
<VirtualHost _default:443>
 <Proxy */api>
   Require all granted
 </Proxy>

# API
  ProxyPass /api/  "http://localhost:9000/"
  ProxyPassReverse /api/ "http://localhost:9000/"

  #REACT APP FRONT END
  ProxyPass  / "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
  ProxyPassReverse  /  "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"

</VirtualHost>
```

I have added a Location tag pointing to the localhost:9000 express app bin folder, after doing the usual Directory tag to define the express app file serving directory, but still getting denied.

I suspect it is some other conf files on the Bitnami MEAN Lightsail box that are impacting my VirtualHost, as I have this working locally on my generic Apache build. Hoping someone who is familiar with the Bitnami nuances might have some insight. The docs provided at Bitnami don't match the default setup on the server, so it's been sort of experimental.

When connected to the machine via console, I can curl to localhost:9000 on the box from a local console and hit the service which returns JSON -  all looks well there, so there is no question that the web service is really running.

The 2nd ProxyPass pointing at "/" does indeed work for the react app via the localhost:3000 proxy.

This is working locally on my system, so it must be some Bitnami configuration gotcha somewhere or the IPv4 /  IPv6 issue.

Has anyone run into this problem?